# gitignore what is the meaning of *~ and these other patterns?

Tags: git, gitignore

I came across [this .gitignore file](https://github.com/munen/p_slides/blob/master/.gitignore) and could not understand it. Especially the first line `*~` and the second one also.

Here are the complete contents for quick reference:

```
*~
\#*\#
*.swp
tmp/*
private/**/*
public/cache
.DS_Store
.#*
example_presentation.html
```

Please explain it. Where does one find the detailed syntax of patterns used by gitignore, (apart from the man-pages)?

I have already tried the man-pages, but sad to say, I found the patterns descriptions there to be less helpful. Hence the question.

Comment: The first line is ignore anything ending with a tilde (`~`), the second line is ignore anything beginning or ending with a `\#`. Double glob (`**`) means match in all directories, in other words ignore anything matching in all directories/sub-directories.

Answer (score 7):

There are two classes of expressions one put in a `.gitignore` file: expressions that match temporary files, backup files or files used by the development tools and expressions that match files from your project.

The first class matches files that are not needed by your project because they are generated by the tools, either for their own use or as backup of the files they modify.

The second class matches files that are needed by your project but they are either generated by the project's code or they are configuration files that contain sensitive information (i.e. passwords) and configuration settings that depend on the computer where the project runs.

The patterns you posted:

1. backups, temporary files etc:

   - `*~` - file names ending in `~` - they are created as backup copies by some editors on OSX and Linux; the Windows software usually replaces the file extension with `.bak` (or appends it);
   - `\#*\#` - quote from the [documentation of `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore): *"A line starting with `#`  serves as a comment. Put a backslash (`"\"`) in front of the first hash for patterns that begin with a hash."* -- this means the second `#` doesn't need to be escaped.

     I don't know what software produces files whose name start and end with a `#` but, most probably, they are temporary files;
   - `*.swp` - temporary files used by [`vi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) to detect simultaneous edits of a file by two instances of the editor;
   - `.DS_Store` - files created by OSX Finder in each directory; they contain its internal bookeeping (thumbnails, sort order etc);
   - `.#*` - files whose names start with `.#`; <del>I don't know any application that generates them;</del> [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) uses `.#*` for lock files to detect simultaneous edits (thanks @TobySpeight); there is no need to escape the `#`, see above;
2. files used by your project but not needed in the repository:

   - `tmp/*` - many web applications generate temporary files in a directory named `tmp` or `var/tmp` or similar;
   - `public/cache` - the `public` directory is the part of the project that is visible through the web server; the `cache` subdirectory probably contains generated files (f.e. concatenated and minified scripts and CSS files) - they need to be visible from outside (public) without other processing but not needed in the repository because they are, well, generated during runtime;
   - `private/**/*`, `example_presentation.html` - these two are too specific; only your project can explain why the repository should ignore them.

Comment: Just curious: I figured the `#` had to be escaped in `.gitignore` so that explains `\#*\#`. But why is it not escaped in `.#*`? A typo maybe? Perhaps you only have to escape lines beginning with `#` but then why wouldn't `\#*\#` be `\#*#` instead?

Comment: Emacs uses `.#*` for lock files to detect simultaneous edits.

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you. I never used emacs; in fact, I tried several times but every time I returned back to vi :-)

Comment: @JonnyHenly I just updated the answer with a quote from the `.gitignore` documentation; it seems the first pattern should be `\#*#` and the second one (`.#*`) doesn't need escaping. Thank you for the comment; I didn't know the exact rules of comments and escaping of `#` in `.gitignore`; I know them now. :-)

Comment: private/**/* assuming there are not spaces in there seems a bit strange to me.  Why ** ?  

I guess that would match private/something/other but not private/other (since the / is counted as character)?

Update:  just saw the definition of double glob above (in comment on OP) but still not sure what that means...

Comment: @AshleyAitken It is explained in the documentation of [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore): *"Two consecutive asterisks ("`**`") in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning: ([read more](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore))"*.

Answer (score 1):

The patterns are standard glob patterns; see the `glob(7)` man page:

> - A **`?`** (not between brackets) matches any single character.
> - A **`*`** (not between brackets) matches any string, including the empty string.
> - An  expression **`[...]`**  where  the  first  character after the leading `[` is not an `!` matches a single character, namely any of the characters enclosed by the brackets.  The string enclosed by the brackets cannot be empty; therefore `]` can be allowed between the
>        brackets, provided that it is the first character.  (Thus, `[][!]` matches the three characters `[`, `]` and `!`.)
> - There is one special convention: two characters separated by `-` denote a range.  (Thus, `[A-Fa-f0-9]` is equivalent to `[ABCDEFabcdef0123456789]`.)  One may include `-` in its literal meaning by making it the first or last character  between  the  brackets.   (Thus,
>        `[]-]` matches just the two characters `]` and `-`, and `[--0]` matches the three characters `-`, `.`, `0`, since `/` cannot be matched.)
> - An expression **`[!...]`** matches a single character, namely any character that is not matched by the expression obtained by removing the first `!` from it.  (Thus, `[!]a-]` matches any single character except `]`, `a` and `-`.)
>
> One  can  remove the special meaning of `?`, `*` and `[` by preceding them by a backslash.  Between brackets these characters stand for themselves.  Thus, `[[?*\]` matches the four characters
>          `[`, `?`, `*` and `\`.

Answer (score 0):

`*~` matches any filename that ends with `~`.  Some text editors create files ending in `~` as autosaves for backup purposes.  It makes sense to ignore these files.